# Unable to get libboost_locale files when building Boost.Locale

Tags: c++, macos, boost, build, locale

My computer was updated recently, from macOS 10.13 (High Sierra) to 12.6 (Monterey).

I had successfully built the Boost C++ libraries on 10.13, using boost version 1.66.0, with *filesystem*, *system*, *regex* and *locale* libraries.

Now, I'm trying to build the same Boost libraries on 12.6.3, using boost version 1.82.0. Apart from *locale*, every other libraries from the list are building correctly (I can see them created in /boost_1_82_0/stage/lib). Apparently, nor *libboost_locale.a* or *libboost_locale.dylib* are created, even if I see no error or warning messages after the building process.

Just to be sure, for testing I'm only trying to build with *locale*. I had to install *libiconv* from homebrew since it was a required dependency to install PostgreSQL 15. Then, after trying to install Boost with *locale*, I installed *icu4c* with homebrew in a desperate attempt to get it to build properly. I tried uninstalling one or another of those and tried again, even removing both with no success. While the boost building process is not complaining, it's not creating the desired output files either.

I followed the usual steps to build boost, initially executing `./bootstrap.sh`, then `./b2 --with-locale`

Before each try, I execute: `./b2 clean`.

Here's the output I get when building:

```
[errno 2] .jam (No such file or directory)
Performing configuration checks

    - default address-model    : 64-bit (cached) [1]
    - default architecture     : x86 (cached) [1]

Building the Boost C++ Libraries.


    - iconv (libc)             : no  (cached) [2]
    - iconv (separate)         : yes (cached) [2]
    - icu                      : no  (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_auto_declarations  : no  (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_decltype           : no  (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_defaulted_functions : no  (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_defaulted_moves    : no  (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_hdr_functional     : no  (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_hdr_type_traits    : no  (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_noexcept           : no  (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_nullptr            : no  (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_override           : no  (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_range_based_for    : no  (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_rvalue_references  : no  (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_scoped_enums       : no  (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_smart_ptr          : no  (cached) [2]
    - cxx11_static_assert      : no  (cached) [2]
    - iconv (libc)             : no  (cached) [3]
    - iconv (separate)         : yes (cached) [3]
    - icu                      : no  (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_auto_declarations  : no  (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_decltype           : no  (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_defaulted_functions : no  (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_defaulted_moves    : no  (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_hdr_functional     : no  (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_hdr_type_traits    : no  (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_noexcept           : no  (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_nullptr            : no  (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_override           : no  (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_range_based_for    : no  (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_rvalue_references  : no  (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_scoped_enums       : no  (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_smart_ptr          : no  (cached) [3]
    - cxx11_static_assert      : no  (cached) [3]
    - iconv (libc)             : no  (cached) [4]
    - iconv (separate)         : yes (cached) [4]
    - icu                      : no  (cached) [4]
    - cxx11_auto_declarations  : no  (cached) [4]
    - cxx11_decltype           : no  (cached) [4]
    - cxx11_defaulted_functions : no  (cached) [4]
    - cxx11_defaulted_moves    : no  (cached) [4]
    - cxx11_hdr_functional     : no  (cached) [4]
    - cxx11_hdr_type_traits    : no  (cached) [4]
    - cxx11_noexcept           : no  (cached) [4]
    - cxx11_nullptr            : no  (cached) [4]
    - cxx11_override           : no  (cached) [4]
    - cxx11_range_based_for    : no  (cached) [4]
    - cxx11_rvalue_references  : no  (cached) [4]
    - cxx11_scoped_enums       : no  (cached) [4]
    - cxx11_smart_ptr          : no  (cached) [4]
    - cxx11_static_assert      : no  (cached) [4]
    - iconv (libc)             : no  (cached) [5]
    - iconv (separate)         : yes (cached) [5]
    - icu                      : no  (cached) [5]
    - cxx11_auto_declarations  : no  (cached) [5]
    - cxx11_decltype           : no  (cached) [5]
    - cxx11_defaulted_functions : no  (cached) [5]
    - cxx11_defaulted_moves    : no  (cached) [5]
    - cxx11_hdr_functional     : no  (cached) [5]
    - cxx11_hdr_type_traits    : no  (cached) [5]
    - cxx11_noexcept           : no  (cached) [5]
    - cxx11_nullptr            : no  (cached) [5]
    - cxx11_override           : no  (cached) [5]
    - cxx11_range_based_for    : no  (cached) [5]
    - cxx11_rvalue_references  : no  (cached) [5]
    - cxx11_scoped_enums       : no  (cached) [5]
    - cxx11_smart_ptr          : no  (cached) [5]
    - cxx11_static_assert      : no  (cached) [5]

[1] clang-13
[2] clang-darwin-13/release/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden
[3] clang-darwin-13/release/build-no/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden
[4] clang-darwin-13/release/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden
[5] clang-darwin-13/release/build-no/link-static/threadapi-pthread/threading-multi/visibility-hidden

Component configuration:

    - atomic                   : not building
    - chrono                   : not building
    - container                : not building
    - context                  : not building
    - contract                 : not building
    - coroutine                : not building
    - date_time                : not building
    - exception                : not building
    - fiber                    : not building
    - filesystem               : not building
    - graph                    : not building
    - graph_parallel           : not building
    - headers                  : not building
    - iostreams                : not building
    - json                     : not building
    - locale                   : building
    - log                      : not building
    - math                     : not building
    - mpi                      : not building
    - nowide                   : not building
    - program_options          : not building
    - python                   : not building
    - random                   : not building
    - regex                    : not building
    - serialization            : not building
    - stacktrace               : not building
    - system                   : not building
    - test                     : not building
    - thread                   : not building
    - timer                    : not building
    - type_erasure             : not building
    - url                      : not building
    - wave                     : not building

...found 20 targets...
...updating 4 targets...
boost-install.generate-cmake-config-version- bin.v2/tools/boost_install/BoostConfigVersion.cmake
common.copy /Volumes/programmation/boost_1_82_0/stage/lib/cmake/BoostDetectToolset-1.82.0.cmake
common.copy /Volumes/programmation/boost_1_82_0/stage/lib/cmake/Boost-1.82.0/BoostConfig.cmake
common.copy /Volumes/programmation/boost_1_82_0/stage/lib/cmake/Boost-1.82.0/BoostConfigVersion.cmake
...updated 4 targets...


The Boost C++ Libraries were successfully built!

The following directory should be added to compiler include paths:

    /Volumes/programmation/boost_1_82_0

The following directory should be added to linker library paths:

    /Volumes/programmation/boost_1_82_0/stage/lib
```

As I understand it, Boost.Locale requires either *ICU* or *iconv* to build. The output specifies it can retrieve *iconv (separate)*, is that sufficient?

Please tell me if I should include more details.

Comment: Have you ever found the cause? I have exactly the same effect, only on Ventura 13.5

Comment: Hi @PavelZdenek, no unfortunately I am considering not using this Boost library anymore, I can't seem to make it work...

Comment: Thank you, it confirms our intent to keep going with STL <codecvt> despite its abrupt deprecation in C++17 without recommending an alternative. We did our research of the alternatives; the lack of recommendation is somewhat understandable. We can't use ICU anyway because the "libicudata" mothership on its own is bigger than the kernel of our target embedded system.

Comment: That's what I did too